# Algolia Duplicates

Tags: javascript, node.js, algolia

I'm having a bit of trouble getting Algolia to work properly. I'm using NodeJS and am trying to have a bit of synchronization going between my database and Algolia, but for some reason a ton of duplicates seem to pop up randomly.

[image]

As you can see, in some cases two different entries are popping up with completely different data except for the topic name. I am not running the add-to-algolia code anywhere else, and the UUID is off as entries I put in have "topic-" in front of them.

```js
function loadNewTweets(){
 console.log("Checking...");
 var tweets;
 var topics;
 var referenceTopics;
 Promise.all([
  //stuff
 ])
 .then(function(data){
    
    topics = [
      //data
    ]
    
  return Promise.each(topics, function(topic, index){
   return new Promise(function(res,rej){
    Promise.all([
     //things
    ])
    .then(function(r){
     var id = 'topic-'+uuid.v4();

     if(!topicDB){
      var obj = {
       //data
      }
      console.log("Adding", topic.topic, "to topic DB + Algolia");
      return new Promise(function(res,rej){
       var dbInstance;
       Database.models.Topic.create(obj)
       .then(function(topic){
        dbInstance = topic;
        return Search.addData('topics', [dbInstance])
       })
       .then(function(content){
        dbInstance.algoliaId = content.objectIDs[0];
        return dbInstance.save(['algoliaId']);
       })
       .then(function(){
        return res();
       })
      })
     }
    })
    .then(function(){
     return res();
    })
   })
   
  })
 })
 .then(function(){
  return Database.models.Topic.findAll({})
 })
 .then(function(topicsDB){
  //If a topic is in the database, but not the topics array.

  //Loop through each database entry.
  Promise.each(topicsDB, function(topic){
   var del = true;

   //Go through topics array
   for(var i=0;i<topics.length;i++){

    //If a topic in the array matches a database entry, dont remove it.
    if(topics[i].topic == topic.topic){
     del = false;
    }
   }

   //If no entry was found in the array for this topic in the database, remove it from the database and Algolia.
   if(del){
    console.log("Deleting", topic.topic, "from topic DB + Algolia", topic.algoliaId);
    Search.delete('topics', [topic.algoliaId])
    .then(function(){
     topic.destroy();
    })
   }
  })
 })
}
```

Is there some sort of option I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: There seems to be some sort of relationship between the duplicate and the original, but I still cant figure out what's causing it.

[image]

(forgive the bar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is embarrassing.

I forgot about a staging server that was also contributing to the index.

Comment: Does this mean that you found the root of your problem?

Answer (score 4):

There are duplicates because you are not using the [objectID][1] to uniquely identify your records. Usually a primary key works fine as an objectID. If you don't specify one, Algolia will assign one automatically which means that it will hard to not have duplicates.

```
{
   name: 'some name',
   objectID: 'the id of the data in my database'
}
```

There are examples in the documentation: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/save-objects/#examples

Comment: how do you define an objectID though? inside or outside the scope of index.saveobjects?

Comment: @ToanLam You can define the objectID directly in the object.